# Chrome extension get chrome page request body details

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, request

I am making custom chrome extension. I would like to get body of a request that is made after clicking a button on a page. So my extension runs in the background and I click on a button on page and my chrome extension gets this request body that runs after clicking. Is there any possibility to do that in javascript? The problem is that I need JSON data from that body but I cannot get it without making this request that is after clicking on the button. It is actual user information ID. Right now I have to make it manually - go to chrome developer tools > go to network tab > click on a button > find my request > check body of it and get data. I would like to make it automatic by my chrome extension.

Comment: If the request is just GET method and has not side effect to the webapp, you can try to inject content script to the page that fetch the request manually.

Comment: @GyDi I am not sure if I understand, fetch the request manually? what do you mean?

Comment: I mean that you can see the request in the network, then you can simulate the request using `fetch`.

Comment: @GyDi yes but the problem is that to make it using `fetch` I have to know clientID which I don't know without making request manually and checking body

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution by using [chrome.webRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webRequest/). It is possible to catch request that I was looking for and get it's payload and data.